# Dell latitude E6400 heat issue

Tags: cooling, temperature, overheating, dell-latitude, heatsink

My laptop heats up in just an hour, i cleaned the Ram, Heat Sink,and Motherboard. 
Everything is clean and clear . i Installed windows 7 professional 64 bit (LOCAL, Registered).

My laptop Ram is 2GB, Processor Clock Speed is 2.53, with an Nvidia graphics card.
Bios version is A34.

Comment: you do not mention anything about a fan. Is it working? rotating freely?

Comment: Yup fan is working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend downloading and installing SpeedFan and having it run during use of your day. you can download it here http://www.almico.com/speedfan450.exe
be aware that this may be a direct download link to speed fan.
the link for the page to download is here http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php

hope this helps and by the way i use this myself but if you have a fan issue it is best to consult a technician